# 64-bit Preference Pane Displays Window

Tags: cocoa, macos

I've developed a preference pane which initially was being built with the Architectures build setting set to "32-bit Universal" (was the default).  This caused System Preferences to relaunch in 32-bit mode but the preference pane worked fine.

I switched Architectures to "Standard (32/64-bit Universal)" and set garbage collection to "Supported".  System Preferences no longer reloads into 32-bit mode, but when it runs it first opens my nib's window outside of System Preferences and for a split second I see all my controls in that window.  The controls then move to the System Preferences window, but the window stays behind with nothing in it.

How do I get rid of this window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder, there is an option on the window to the effect of "Visible upon launch".

Is that enabled? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: That's it!  It's funny it didn't happen when it was 32-bit.  Maybe it was something to do with timing during the restart.

Thank you!